# How to make a dynamic row column another dynamic row in stores -> configuration

Tags: configuration, file-upload, dynamic-rows

i am trying to make dynamic row field type another dynamic row, it is possible in form, i already have a example, but in ui_component form like this[image]

in form it is made by xml, but in stores configuration elements makes by php code, i already tried this variant:

```
    $this->addColumn('role_files', array(
        'label' => __('Files'),
        'style' => 'width:600px',
        'renderer' => $this->getFileSelectRender()
    ));

protected function getFileSelectRender()
{
    return $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Astrio\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\DynamicRowFiles',
            '',
            array('data' => array('is_render_to_js_template' => true))
        );
}
```

Where DynamicRowFiles is

```
class DynamicRowFiles extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
```

but it is not working,it just broke the page:
[image]

Is it possible to do? Actualy i am trying to make uploading multiple files to one row, may be exist another way?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?